# Output JSON-LD script, loaded via angularjs $http

Tags: angularjs, json-ld

I'm trying to get and output JSON-LD data on the page via $http as follow:

```js
angular.element(document).ready(function(){        
        $http({
            url:'/product-init',
            method:'POST',
            data:{product_id:$scope.product_id}
        }).then(function(d){
            $scope.product= d.data;
            $scope.jsonLd={
              "@context":"http://schema.org",
              "@type":"Product"
              // atc.....
            }
            $('#json-ld-content').html(JSON.stringify($scope.jsonLd));
        },function(d){
            alert('product init error');            
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/ld+json" id="json-ld-content"></script>
```

I can see the output in web inspector (on the "Elements" tab), but when I run a [check],[1](http://linter.structured-data.org/) it shows nothing.

Creating *script* tag by *javascript* and then setting html, doesn't help as well.
Also I've found example of loading JSON-LD via AJAX: [it](http://freizeitler.de/examples/json-ld/index.php) works fine.

What's the difference between my case and example above? How to fix my code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structured data linter you referenced doesn't evaluate JavaScript. Try [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) instead.

Comment: Actually, example I've found use JQuery and works on that linter. However, Google's tool work in my case.Thank you :)